# why the commit hang after close the commit message edit window

Tags: linux, git, terminal, git-commit

I am using [cz-cli](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli) to format the commit message right now. First step, using `cz` command in terminal then the terminal will popup a window in Visual Studio and type the commit message into it, after close the commit message edit window in Visual Studio, the terminal message was hang up. why did this happen? I have to using `ctrl + C` to forbidden to exit the commit process. I am not sure this is the right way to handle this situation.

[image]

PS: this command was to running in GitHub Codespaces.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative would be to work directly in:

- Visual Studio ([`vs-commitizen`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrluje.vs-commitizen))
- VSCode ([`vscode-commitizen`](https://github.com/KnisterPeter/vscode-commitizen))

That way, there is no back an forth between an external shell and your IDE.

[image: Visual Studio --]